# build/install configure error can't create

Tags: compiling, configuration

I know it's been beat to death, but I'm at my wits end with this.  I've followed all the entries that I can take. I'm trying to build this program on Debian 8.6.  I added the blank line where I grep the config.log file. Here is the path and output from the configuration.

```
jack@Kilo:~/mnt/dev-test/avarice-2.13$ echo $PATH
/bin:/usr/bin
jack@Kilo:~/mnt/dev-test/avarice-2.13$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/jack/mnt/dev-test/avarice-2.13':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

jack@Kilo:~/mnt/dev-test/avarice-2.13$ egrep error config.log
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
g++: fatal error: no input files
configure:2989: error: in `/home/jack/mnt/dev-test/avarice-2.13':
configure:2991: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
jack@Kilo:~/mnt/dev-test/avarice-2.13$
```

Here is the config.log file

```
jack@Kilo:~/mnt/dev-test/avarice-2.13$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/jack/mnt/dev-test/avarice-2.13':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
jack@Kilo:~/mnt/dev-test/avarice-2.13$ egrep error config.log
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
g++: fatal error: no input files
configure:2989: error: in `/home/jack/mnt/dev-test/avarice-2.13':
configure:2991: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
jack@Kilo:~/mnt/dev-test/avarice-2.13$ cat config.log
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by avarice configure 2.13, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = Kilo
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 3.16.0-4-amd64
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19)

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /usr/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2289: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2357: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2368: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2423: result: yes
configure:2574: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:2613: result: /bin/mkdir -p
configure:2620: checking for gawk
configure:2636: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:2647: result: gawk
configure:2658: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2680: result: yes
configure:2826: checking for g++
configure:2842: found /usr/bin/g++
configure:2853: result: g++
configure:2880: checking for C++ compiler version
configure:2889: g++ --version >&5
g++ (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2900: $? = 0
configure:2889: g++ -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.9.2-10' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.9 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.9 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --with-arch-32=i586 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10) 
configure:2900: $? = 0
configure:2889: g++ -qversion >&5
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2900: $? = 4
configure:2920: checking whether the C++ compiler works
configure:2942: g++    conftest.cpp  >&5
as: unrecognized option '--64'
configure:2946: $? = 1
configure:2984: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "avarice"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "avarice"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.13"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "avarice 2.13"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "avarice"
| #define VERSION "2.13"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2989: error: in `/home/jack/mnt/dev-test/avarice-2.13':
configure:2991: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CXX=g++
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /home/jack/mnt/dev-test/avarice-2.13/config-aux/missing --run aclocal-1.12'
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AM_CPPFLAGS=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /home/jack/mnt/dev-test/avarice-2.13/config-aux/missing --run autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /home/jack/mnt/dev-test/avarice-2.13/config-aux/missing --run autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /home/jack/mnt/dev-test/avarice-2.13/config-aux/missing --run automake-1.12'
AWK='gawk'
CC=''
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX='g++'
CXXDEPMODE=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
GREP=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /home/jack/mnt/dev-test/avarice-2.13/config-aux/missing --run makeinfo'
MKDIR_P='/bin/mkdir -p'
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE='avarice'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='avarice'
PACKAGE_STRING='avarice 2.13'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='avarice'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='2.13'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP=''
VERSION='2.13'
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX='g++'
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCXX_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep=''
am__quote=''
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build_alias=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host_alias=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /home/jack/mnt/dev-test/avarice-2.13/config-aux/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pathperl=''
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "avarice"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "avarice"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.13"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "avarice 2.13"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE "avarice"
#define VERSION "2.13"

configure: exit 77
jack@Kilo:~/mnt/dev-test/avarice-2.13$
```

I found the error that said the g++ compiler works -> no. I use eclipse and it and the Arduino and command line compile and link g++ code. So..

```
jack@Kilo:~/mnt/dev-test/avarice-2.13$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.9.2-10' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.9 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.9 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --with-arch-32=i586 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10) 
jack@Kilo:~/mnt/dev-test/avarice-2.13$ which g++
/usr/bin/g++
jack@Kilo:~/mnt/dev-test/avarice-2.13$ ls -l /usr/bin/g++
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Feb 25  2015 /usr/bin/g++ -> g++-4.9
jack@Kilo:~/mnt/dev-test/avarice-2.13$
```

Thanks for whatever anyone can do for me.  I hope I've included enough information.

Jack :)

Comment: What does `as -V < /dev/null` output?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by re installing binutils.  It appears that the AVR tool chain was the default and reinstalling binutils fixed up the problem.  Don't know about my avr stuff... :)

Thanks